# firefox and IE does not lose focus when a link is clicked, but Chrome does

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, focus, anchor, blur

I have a list of anchors which are styled to change appearance on focus and hover. And after they are clicked they are supposed to go back to normal; lose focus/become blurred. This works as expected in Google Chrome, but in firefox and IE it doesn't, it stays in focus. Why is that so?

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/8fTQs/

My guess is that FF and IE expects the page to reload when an anchor is clicked, but since these are just referring to an anchorpoint (#; hash) it does not re-render the page (but if it was reloaded it would of course re-render and lose focus).

How do one go around this?

Thank you!

Edit: I have set a proper doctype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focusing the anchor on click is the right behavior even if the page is not reloaded: it makes tab navigation work correctly after that point.

It sounds like you want to be styling `:active` anchors, not `:focus` ones, if you want styling only while the anchor is being clicked.

Comment: Oh. Well, I guess that solves my problem. Than however, I have another problem. I want the links to be navigated by tabbing, so they need to "show" (change style) when one have navigated to that link by tabbing (being active). Do you have a solution to this as well?

Comment: No, unfortunately.  Tabbing doesn't make a link active until the user hits enter; it just makes it focused....

Comment: You sure? :S Because if the style says ":active{background...}" and I tab to them they will change background, but if the style is ":focus{background...}" and I tab to them they do not change.

Edit: however the links do get a border to them. (":focus{background...}")

Comment: Yes, pretty sure.  Try http://jsfiddle.net/AuUCr/ : in Firefox I see the :focus but not the :active trigger when tabbing.

Comment: True. But than again if I hit enter (when tabbed to :focus) the style stays. I want it to disappear when clicked.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  The point is that you can't really do that: CSS just doesn't have the state you want.  It knows about focused things, and active things, but not the particular mix you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You still need a `:focus` style to help [keyboard navigation](http://24ways.org/2009/dont-lose-your-focus/), so you better not remove it.

Chrome doesn't keep focus after a click but FF and IE do. What you can do is *normalize* the behavior but blurring the link every time it's clicked — but only **clicked!**

A simple `$('a').click(function () {this.blur();})` would blur the element *(blur = lose focus)* but browsers (or just jQuery) also fires the "click" event when you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

So a quick and dirty solution would be: `$('a').mouseup(function () {this.blur();})`

Answer (score 0):

The correct behaviour is that focus **should be left** on the anchor after mouse-click (as the FF and IE does it now).

Registered [chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=388666) is fixed and the [patch](https://codereview.chromium.org/455223002) created Aug 14, 2014 is under review. Should get the fix in the upcoming updates.

Comment: Issue still exists, I think the patch didn't get added for backward compatibility reasons.